# Why aren't my rose seeds germinating?

Tags: flowers, germination, roses

I had ordered blue rose seeds online. I got 5 seeds. I chose 3 seeds and sowed them in a small pot with soil and have been watering them for last 2 weeks. I have kept the pot indoors, covered with a white dish.

1. Am I being impatient and should A wait a little longer?
2. Did I get a bad deal from the online seller?
3. Have I done something wrong while trying to germinate the seed?

I have kept other two seeds in plastic bag which I will try plant again if these three have gone horribly wrong.

Weather: 15 deg cel to 35 deg cel currently.

Location: Pune India

Comment: If they don't germinate in any reasonable amount of time and you don't need the pot for anything else, just keep it moist anyway and they may grow in their own time. Do the stratification thing first though.

Comment: Is there something you would like me to add to my answer?

Comment: Please tell me.  When you say you ordered a blue rose.  Did you order one of many roses named blue something or another, but actually a pale lilac blue at best or did you see a photo of a really blue blue rose?   I am finding many fake plant seeds been sold online. They take normal coloured photos, often white and make them blue in a photo editing program.  Often the seeds they send are not the plant they say they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to stratify the seeds. Also, it often takes over 5 weeks for germination, even under good conditions.

For more information on growing roses from seed, see:

[How do I grow roses from seed?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5548/how-do-i-grow-roses-from-seed)

From that post:

> The seeds of roses have within them a protein that prevents germination. This protein degrades and the seed can germinate only when subjected to temperature changes. In fact, the seed must "feel" that autumn has arrived, winter has passed, and spring, the best time to be born, has arrived.

That's what stratification is for. On another note, you said you ordered 'blue rose seeds'. 'Blue' roses are usually hybrids, so their seedlings tend to be more pink/red. Whoever you ordered them from may not have known this. Keep that in mind, and don't be surprised if the resulting seedlings (if you get them to germinate) are not 'blue' roses. It's easy to buy seeds from less than spectacular growers online, so you *might* have gotten ripped off.

Also, they like a specific mix to germinate in, not just 'soil'. Please see the link above for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the link and detailed answer JM. I will be sad if i dont get blue roses. keeping fingers crossed.. I will wait for few more weeks for the seeds to germinate. I will post the picture here once they germinate.